# Golang: Retrieving Gorilla/Sessions Cookie

Tags: session, authentication, cookies, go, gorilla

I'm trying to find out the cookie value that is being saved to the clients browser via s.Save(r, w). That way I can store the cookie value in a database before calling renderTemplate(). Is there a way to accomplish this using the gorilla/sessions api?

```
func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, db *sql.DB, store *sessions.CookieStore, t *template.Template){
  if r.Method == "POST" {
    r.ParseForm()
    username, password, remember := r.FormValue("user[name]"), r.FormValue("user[password]"), r.FormValue("remember_me")
    User, err := users.Login(db, username, password, remember, r.RemoteAddr)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }
    s, _ := store.Get(r, "rp-session")  //returns a new session
    s.Save(r, w)
    //fmt.Println(s.Values)
    renderTemplate(w, "user_nav_info", t, User)
  } 
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: what value is there in storing the (encoded) cookie value in your own database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how gorilla's sessions api saves the session - https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/master/store.go#L104-L109

So, you can essentially include the below code to get the exact cookie value being set in client's machine.

```
encoded, err := securecookie.EncodeMulti(s.Name(), s.Values, store.Codecs...)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
cookieVal := NewCookie(s.Name(), encoded, s.Options)
fmt.Println(cookieVal) // cookie value that is sent to client
```

Although, I'd not suggest you to save the cookie that way. gorilla's sessions api is supposed to the job for you.

Comment: Thanks this did the job.